# Worked well but suddenly shows error. Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I made a function in a google spreadsheet and it worked well until now.

The error sign popped up saying

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.

```
function player(id){

    var url = "https://shashanks.ga/node/getPlayers?playerID="+id;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
    response = JSON.parse(response)
    var name = response.name;
    var townhall = response.townHallLevel;
    
    var data = [name,townhall];
  
    return data;
}
```

This is my script. What should I do?

Comment: What do you think the error message is trying to tell you?

Comment: i have no idea...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885035/service-invoked-too-many-times-for-one-day-urlfetch-google-sheets-error

Comment: thanks for the advice but plz can you help me with editing my script?
I am just a newbie in java...

Answer (score 0):

There is a [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) per day for `urlFetchApp.fetch` commands.

[image]

Make sure not to go beyond that quota as it will cause failures. It will reset the next day, so you can wait for that to happen.

The reason why you reach the quota is that your calls might be re-fetching the result multiple times. You might need to cache your data like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62813073/14606045)